# C# random imgur generator to use with Skypetool

Tags: random

I'm trying to create skype tool and I'm trying to make a command for it what would give the user a random imgur link, I tried first to just random generate string like so:

```
var chars ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var stringChars = new char[8];
var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
{
    stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
}

var finalString = new String(stringChars);

string imgur = "http://imgur.com/" + finalString;
```

But of course it just gave me random imgur links which don't work, how could I check if the link is valid and then give it to the user or how could I use imgurs own "https://imgur.com/gallery/random" and return the link from that?

Answer (score 0):

Imgur API exposes a function to fetch a random set of gallery images:

https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#gallery-random

```
Method  GET
Route   https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/random/random/{page}
```